# List not getting updated in Tensorflow v1.14

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I am using the following code to achieve a left shift operation in the TensorArray `old_array`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

old_array = [tf.zeros((1, 2)), tf.zeros((1, 2))]

def left_shift(ol=None):
    if ol is None:
        ol = old_array
    val = tf.random.normal((1, 2))
    an_array = [ol[1], val]
    return an_array

old_array = left_shift().copy()

sess = tf.Session()

for _ in range(5):
    x, y = sess.run([old_array, left_shift()])
    # y = sess.run(left_shift())
    print(y)
```

There are no errors in the code but `x[0]` is always a collection of `0`'s. `x[1]` is changing with each iteration. `y` has the desired result.

What is wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: If there is an easier way to do a left shift operation in Tensorflow, please let me know.

Comment: By Left Shift Operation, do you mean Bitwise Left Shift.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport I mean shift the second entry of a list to the first entry of the same list